# WebComponent - Difference between shadow DOM and append on connectedCallback

Tags: javascript, html, dom

In the context of WebComponenet, what is the difference between attaching an element using the connectedCallback() method and using shadow DOM?

Examples with shadow DOM:

```
class MyWebComponent extends HTMLElement {
 constructor() {
          super();
          const shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
          shadow.innerHTML = 'Hello, World!';
  }
}
customElements.define('my-web-component', MyWebComponent);
```

Example with connectedCallback() method:

```
class MyWebComponent extends HTMLElement {
 connectedCallback() {
    const template = document.createElement('template');
    template.innerHTML = 'Hello, World!';
    this.append(template.content.cloneNode(true));
 }
}
customElements.define('my-web-component', MyWebComponent);
```

The result is exactly the same, so I would like to understand more about the differences between the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constructor: The constructor is called when the element is created. Attributes are not accessible at this stage. At this point, the component is "empty" meaning it does not yet have any attributes or content. However, you can populate it with shadow HTML content.

connectedCallback(): This method is called when the element is connected to the DOM. Attributes are now accessible, and this is the appropriate place to access and use them.

so If the content of the component depends on its attributes, it is better to use "connectedCallback."

example:

```
class MyWebComponent extends HTMLElement {
 constructor() {
          super();
          const shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'}); 

          const user = this.getAttribute('user') || 'Default';      

          shadow.innerHTML = 'Hello, ' + user;
  }
}
customElements.define('my-web-component', MyWebComponent);
```

and

```
class MyWebComponent2 extends HTMLElement {
   connectedCallback() {
          const shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'}); 

          const user = this.getAttribute('user') || 'Default';      

          shadow.innerHTML = 'Hello, ' + user;
   }
}
customElements.define('my-web-component-cb', MyWebComponent2);
```

and try both of them

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="a.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="b.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <my-web-component user="World"></my-web-component>
    <my-web-component-cb user="World"></my-web-component-cb>
</body>
</html>
```

result will be

```
Hello, Default
Hello, World
```